# Column Width Problem (autoExpandColumn & forceFit set to true in the same grid)

Tags: extjs

I have problem in setting my width column...,

I have a grid with dynamic columns (the first column is static) and I'm using forceFit config to true for preventing horizontal scrolling. But when it shows only 2 columns, the width of the first column is too large.

I haven't been able to upload my screenshot, but you can see them at :
[my last post in sencha (No answer yet)](http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?123429-Column-Width-Problem)

I've tried to use autoExpandColumn config to resize only the first column, But it didn't work :(

How can I achieve it?

Can I use autoExpandColumn & forceFit (set to true) config in the same grid?

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 2):

As quoted from the ExtJS documentation:

> The id of a column in this grid that
>   should expand to fill unused space.
>   This value specified here can not be
>   0.
>
> Note: If the Grid's view is configured
>   with forceFit=true the
>   autoExpandColumn is ignored. See
>   Ext.grid.Column.width for additional
>   details. See autoExpandMax and
>   autoExpandMin also.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your reply Jaitsu, I've tried autoExpandMax and autoExpandMin but it still didn't work. Any solution to achieve my needs? Thanks in Advance

Comment: From the description in your question you just need to set `forceFit: true` in your config, and then assign a `width` property in your first column

Comment: I've tried that way.., but the width of the first column can not be set. I think the forceFit config overrides the width. I just want to minimize the width of the first column..

Comment: * I just want to minimize the width of the first column but if I got many column, there will not be any scroll bar in the grid.

Comment: Ok, the best solution here then is probably to assign static widths to all columns except one. On this one column, give it an ID and assign it to the autoExpandColumn property in your grid config. That way you can be sure that the widths you've set will be obeyed, with your autoExpandColumn filling the remaining gap. I know you only wanted to fix the width of the first column, but I don't think there's any other way around it without getting into an override.

Comment: Ok.., I'll try that.., Thanks for your help. I'll let you know the result later. :)

Answer (score 1):

use flex property of the column set it to 1 for the column which should be expanded at available space.
flex:1